# How to append constant value in parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that uses one parameter. But I need to append some default constant value, something like `this is footer.` or any other parameter.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Try to elaborate your question with some sample input and expected output.so that your question will get more attention.

Comment: declare FromDate = '2016-11-03'; and i need to add '00:00:00.0000' in FromDate parameter so that i can get the output like 2016-11-03 00:00:00.000 while executing query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `FromDate = '2016-11-03'` is string type date. To add constant string to date, you can use below script in your stored procedure

```
SET FromDate = CONVERT( DATETIME, '2016-11-03',101 )
```

OR

```
SET FromDate = CAST( '2016-11-03' AS DATETIME )
```

This will store `FromDate = '2016-11-03 00:00:00.000'`

Comment: And i wanna add another constant string '23:59:59.999' to another parameter (like ToDate = '2016-11-03 23:59:59.999'). How can i do that?

Comment: You can do this by simple concatenation like `SET ToDate = '2016-11-03'+' 23:59:59.999'`

Comment: yeah i get it.Thanks man. I ll do your logic to concatenation.